# Code for pivot table in VBA only works one time

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with 1532 rows and 7 columns called "Delayed Students". I want to make a pivot table in the sheet but every time I use my code, I get a

> run-time error'438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

And this area is yellow (.Position =1):

```
With .PivotFields("FACULTY_ID")
  .Orientation = xlDataField
  .Postion = 1
```

But it creates the pivot table anyways. The problem is when i delete the table and try to use the code again it doesn't create the pivot table again. So something must be wrong with my code:

```
Sub Pivot1()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache

Dim PvtTblName As String
Dim pivotTableWs As Worksheet

PvtTblName = "pivotTableName"

Set pivotTableWs = Sheets("Delayed Students")


Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Delayed Students!R1C1:R1532C7")


Set PvtTbl = pivotTableWs.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=pivotTableWs.Range("J1"), TableName:=PvtTblName)

With PvtTbl
.ColumnGrand = True
.HasAutoFormat = True
.DisplayErrorString = False
.DisplayNullString = True
.EnableDrilldown = True
.ErrorString = ""
.MergeLabels = False
.NullString = ""
.PageFieldOrder = 2
.PageFieldWrapCount = 0
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RowGrand = True
.SaveData = True
.PrintTitles = False
.RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
.TotalsAnnotation = False
.CompactRowIndent = 1
.InGridDropZones = False
.DisplayFieldCaptions = True
.DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
.DisplayContextTooltips = True
.ShowDrillIndicators = True
.PrintDrillIndicators = False
.AllowMultipleFilters = False
.SortUsingCustomLists = True
.FieldListSortAscending = False
.ShowValuesRow = False
.CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
.RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow

With .PivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
End With

.RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels

With .PivotFields("STUDYBOARD_ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With .PivotFields("FACULTY_ID")
  .Orientation = xlDataField
  .Postion = 1


End With
End With



End Sub
```

Hope someone can help me with what i am doing wrong :)

Comment: `Postion` or `Position`? There is no property called `Postion` - you have a typo.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that haha, thank you very much it works now :-)